# Python 3 Socket Transport Endpoint Already Connected Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have wrote simple IRC bot in Python3 but am try to have bot reconnect to IRC network after unreliable internet get disconnect. I detect when get disconnect from server and then try to have exception handler but exception handler always give same error. I shut down socket and then close and then create new socket but still endpoint already connected and give error.

```
...
while True:
        try:
            buffer = buffer + self.irc.recv(1024).decode("utf-8", "replace")
        except ConnectionResetError:
            giveup = 0
            while giveup < 10:
                try:
                    self.irc.connect((self.SERVER, self.PORT))
                except (OSError, socket.gaierror) as e:
                    giveup = giveup + 1
                    print("Connection error, retrying in 90 seconds, attempt %s...\n" % giveup)
                    print(e)
                    self.irc.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                    self.irc.close()
                    self.irc = socket.socket()
                    self.irc.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

                    time.sleep(90)

            if giveup == 10:
                print("Cannot re-establish connection. Exiting.")
                exit()
```

This code give following when try to reconnect:

```
 ...
 [Errno 127] Transport endpoint is already connected
 Connection error, retrying in 90 seconds, attempt 9...
 [Errno 127] Transport endpoint is already connected
 Connection error, retrying in 90 seconds, attempt 10...
 [Errno 127] Transport endpoint is already connected
 Cannot re-establish connection. Exiting.
```

I do not understand why transport endpoint already connected. Socket is being close and new socket create. It may be because Porthas new and not understand something. Please help and thank you.